# Increasing size of frame - Keyboardwillshow - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, frame, swift4

My code seems to work perfect the first time the keyboard is called. The second time the keyboard is called the frame size does not increase.

Here is my code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    let _: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo! as [NSObject : AnyObject]

    let keyboardSize: CGSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
    let offset: CGSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size

    if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            let frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.fullView, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        })

        noteDetails.frame.size.height = noteDetails.frame.size.height + keyboardSize.height
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            let frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.fullView, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        })

        noteDetails.frame.size.height = noteDetails.frame.size.height + keyboardSize.height - offset.height
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let _: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo! as [NSObject : AnyObject]

    let keyboardSize: CGSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size

    noteDetails.frame.size.height = noteDetails.frame.size.height + keyboardSize.height

}
```

I added offset to check for custom keyboard height and to increase the height based on that. I feel that this is causing the code to crash. In specific, by the second time I call the keyboard the height for keyboardSize should be the height of the custom keyboard. Not sure how to fix my code so that the frame of the table increases in height by the height of the keyboard, both for custom keyboards and regular.

Comment: did you try my answer? wondering if it works

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`